# UWP: authorization using Windows credentials

Tags: uwp, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to generate an APP from my website using PWA & UWP (with JS, not C#). The App must work offline and have, obviously, a secure log in.
Ideally would be great using Windows User credentials to log in and let the app check against it. In this way I don't have to store any password anywhere locally. I understand that, in this way, only the current Windows user can have access to the app, but that's not an issue in my case.
Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: [WebAuthenticationBroker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should know more about how to install, run, and enhance your PWA as a Windows 10 app from the document [Tailor your PWA for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps/windows-features#call-winrt-apis-from-your-pwa), after that you can use the UWP WinJS API to get and use the Userinfo.

You can see the official sample to view detailed code:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/UserInfo/js